# In Django, how do I get the name of the pattern that was followed for a particular URL within a template?

Tags: django, django-templates, pattern-matching, url-routing

I have been doing lots of Googling on this topic and have gone through plenty of Django docs, but I can't seem to find a decent answer to what seems like ought to be a very simple question with a simple solution.  So hopefully a Django vet out there can help.

Lets say I have the following urlconf:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ....
    url(r'^directory/users/$', UserView.as_view(), name='users'),
    url(r'^directory/users/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)/$',UserView.as_view(), name='users'),
    ....
)
```

What I want to be able to do is test from within a template which pattern was followed, something like this:

```
{% if name_of_last_followed_url_pattern == 'users' %}
    ....
{% endif %}
```

Now one would think that Django would stash this away somewhere and be able to spit it back out to me.  But I cannot find anything that corresponds to "name_of_last_followed_url_pattern" anywhere in the docs or in my searches.  Any ideas how I might access this (or if not provided, why not)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the context processors that adds the request to the template `django.core.context_processors.request` added to the TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS. Then in the template you can do

```
{% if request.resolver_match.url_name == 'users' %}
....
{% endif %}
```

`resolver_match` has other attributes like namespaces, app_name. You can see here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/urlresolvers/#django.core.urlresolvers.ResolverMatch